# Compiler allows implicit varargs but there seems no way to supply them implicitly

Tags: scala

The following compiles:

```
def test(x:String)(implicit s:String *) = ???
```

However, there seems no way I can supply the implicit `s`.

```
def test2(x:String)(implicit s:String *) =
  test(x) // could not find implicit value for parameter s: String*
```

Am I missing something or should the compiler throw an exception?

Answer (score 1):

This is because inside the method body, the var-args parameters are seen as `Seq[A]` instead of the special type `A*`. You can explicitly expand the sequence again:

```
def test2(x:String)(implicit s:String*) = test(x)(s: _*)
```

Since you cannot define a type as `String*`, it renders the implicit case useless, though:

```
implicit val a = Seq("hallo", "gallo"): _*

// error: no `: _*' annotation allowed here
```

So you will need to use `Seq[String]`.

Comment: Shouldn't the compiler tell me that `implicit s:String *` can never be provided?